# Fitting page size to a tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, paper-size, geometry

Sometimes I'm using `tikz` as a plotting tool, without embedding the figure in a document. In this case, I normally, want to include the resulting PDF in a different TeX file (yes I know I could include the TikZ code directly, but it is not helpful in this case). Therefore, I want the picture to fit exactly to the page, so I won't have white space around it. To this end, I'm using the `geometry` package and `clip` of TikZ. For example, here:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[paperwidth=1cm,paperheight=1cm,hmargin=0cm,vmargin=0cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\draw[red] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\draw[red] (1,0) -- (0,1);
\draw[blue] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Is there a better/nicer/more elegant way to do it?

**EDIT 1:**
*For the sake of clarifying*, I used `clip` because I thought it will make things simpler. Without it, things are actually more straightforward.

**EDIT 2:**

Unfortunately one can only accept one answer. In this case I could accept all. For me, I got to know three new tools, all are slightly different, to accomplish my goal. I choose the Martin's answer due to its standalone nature; no need of neither external tools nor post-proccessing. The other two options yielded more or less the same result.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use the `preview` package with `tightpage,active` options to only display elements you want as single pages. You need to wrap the `tikzpicture` in `preview` environments or declare it as `\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}`.

The `standalone` class gives you exactly this functionality in a very short form:

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\draw[red] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\draw[red] (1,0) -- (0,1);
\draw[blue] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

(Dark border is the PDF viewer background and not part of the PDF)

You then can load the `standalone` *package* (!) in a document and simply `\input` this file. The preamble and `document` environment will be automatically striped.

#### Note:

You are currently clipping at the *center* of the blue rectangle and cutting it in half. You need to add half the line with on each side of the clipping path:

```
\clip (-.5\pgflinewidth,-.5\pgflinewidth) rectangle ([shift={(.5\pgflinewidth,.5\pgflinewidth)}]1,1);
```

Comment: Also the upcoming version of standalone will allow you to use `\includestandalone{file}` and decide if you want to use the `.tex` of the PDF version, and even build the PDF if it is missing.

Comment: It seems to be the best solution, but when I try out your code, the result is *without* the upper&right edges of the blue rectangle. I actually noticed that I have the same problem, I somehow missed it.

Comment: @Dror: I get the full blue rectangle, but it is thinner than the red lines due to the clipping. You need to add `.5\pgflinewidth` on each side of the clipping path. This is not an issue of `standalone` or other solution shown here.

Comment: @Dror: See my update.

Comment: I think I have a viewer problem. Namely, when I try to print-preview I can see a correct and full result (when I remove the clipping). I'm using `preview` of mac os.

Comment: I tried `\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}` in Windows and it worked properly, but in Linux, compiling the same TeX file won't clip the `tikzpicture` as it does in Windows, any comment?

Comment: @Rasoul: I developed `standalone` under Linux, so it should work fine. Please use the above example file and try again. Also, add `\listfiles` before `\begin{document}` and check the log output for the package versions.

Answer (score 11):

I would recommend using Tikz' `external` library for this. It saves all TikZ figures in a document in individual cropped PDFs (and includes them in subsequent runs instead of regenerating the figures). The files will be called `<jobname>-figure<number>.pdf`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Load the library
\usetikzlibrary{external}

% Activate it
\tikzexternalize

% You can uncomment the following to force a remake of all figures
% \tikzset{external/force remake=true} 

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\draw[red] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\draw[red] (1,0) -- (0,1);
\draw[blue] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Externalizing and already external image is kind of overkill, isn't it? Ok, I'm biased. :-)

Comment: You're right, it sounds a bit nonsensical, but I guess it doesn't introduce a dramatic overhead? Furthermore, it has the advantage that you can keep several `tikzpicture`s in the same `.tex` file, e.g. if they use common styles, but still end up with separate PDFs.

Comment: Looks great, although maybe not the best solution for this setting. However, I get the same problem as with my example, and with Martin's example - namely missing upper&right edges of the rectangle...

Comment: @Dror: All the edges are drawn correctly on my system, however your `\clip` action halves the line width of the blue rectangle. If I remove it, everything looks as expected.

Comment: @Jake: I get the same viewer problem I mentioned in Martin's answer. Otherwise, once I remove the clipping, the resulting (derived) file is correct (once I print-preview it).

Comment: It's important to point out that one must compile with `pdflatex -shell-scape`, if you're using `pdflatex`

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`pdfcrop`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop) to automatically remove the white space. So you get a small pdf image which you could include later.

Comment: Thanks! This was the most helpful answer for me, allowing me to automate pdf generation of figures using R and tikzDevice.

Comment: Oh god, this answer is brilliant. This tool is actually autoinstalled with complete LaTeX distributions.