# How can I generate just pgf/TikZ images, not placed a whole page or slide?

Tags: tikz-pgf, document-classes

I'd like to generate only a pgf/TikZ image with LaTeX, but so far I just managed to insert it into a document.
The problem is that so far I can only get a page/a beamer slide rather than just the image I'd like to have.

What document class should I specify to get what I want?

Comment: Have a look at [Fitting page size to a tikz figure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23563/fitting-page-size-to-a-tikz-figure), and please tell us if the answer there (or here) helped. If here, you could accept the answer by clicking the checkmark (you probably know).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Assuming that you are producing the images in a separate document, you can use [the `standalone` class](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone).

For example, this will produce a cropped image by default.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you can include this file directly into your main file and have the image produced there.

Comment: Never saw `standalone` before during several years of latex'ing, but it's just what I needed.  This should definitely become more well known.

Comment: Use `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}` to make this also work when you are using tikz libraries. I don't know why exactly this works. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29875/209725

Comment: I also did not know about this `standalone` feature of latex, although I am using for several years. Thanks @Peter Grill

Answer (score 11):

Just another option is `preview`. With it you can also generate cropped figures but with a great advantage: you can have several figures on the same `.tex` file. The result will be a pdf file with a cropped figure per page. Then you can select which figure include in your document with 'page=' option of `graphicx` package.

One example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[active,pdftex,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{tikz}

\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Process this file and will obtain a pdf with two pages, then select which figure to include in your main document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}\centering
  \includegraphics[page=1]{Preview}%<-- Replace 'Preview' with your figures file's name
  \caption{First rectangle}
 \end{figure}
 \begin{figure}\centering
  \includegraphics[page=2]{Preview}%<-- Replace 'Preview' with your figures file's name
  \caption{Second rectangle}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Update:**

With verson 1.x of `standalone` class you don't need to use `preview` package because my previous description is `standalone` class default behaviour with option `tikz`. So, with this simpler code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

you will also get a pdf file with two pages with one cropped figure in each page.

Comment: This could have been a marvelous idea, but unfortunately it has a flaw: figures are not placed in the same way on the vertical axis. When I use the baseline option of tikzpicture I get the figure nicely placed on the baseline, this disappears when I store it in a PDF file as you suggest. What a pity… It would be nice to have a tikz feature where figures are only compiled once as long as they are not modified (by calculating their signature).

Comment: @yannis Your problem is completly different from this question, but in any case look for `externalize` library. I'm not sure if does what you want but serves to avoid compilation of tikz figures every time you compile your text file.

Comment: unfortunately @Ignasi this library does not work: first of all it crashed at the slightest error (while TeX engine just continues) and then when I managed to get one figure, it refused to go further and compile other figures. In fact it somehow reads the whole TeX file again and again, for each figure, and my file is very complex…

Comment: @yannis Why don't you write a new question explaining your problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you create the `tikzpicture` in an empty document,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf
\pagestyle{empty}% Remove page headers/footers
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  ...
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

you can use [`pdfcrop`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop) to trim the excess edges/whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

What about [KTikZ](http://www.hackenberger.at/blog/ktikz-editor-for-the-tikz-language/) ?

It produces figures from tikz code.