# 'Standalone' TikZ pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, preview

I want to create a TikZ picture in an external PDF file, which then can be included in my main document via `\includegraphics`.
However, compiling a document with a TikZ picture in it produces a whole page, meaning lots of white space.

What I want to do can be done using the preview package as described in [Standalone diagrams with TikZ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701902/standalone-diagrams-with-tikz), on SO. But there are some problems with the preview package and XeTex (see [Transparency in tikz, preview package and xelatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21011/transparency-in-tikz-preview-package-and-xelatex)).

Since creating standalone pictures seems like a natural thing to ask, I am hoping for a different, and maybe more elegant, solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Fitting page size to a tikz figure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23563/fitting-page-size-to-a-tikz-figure) (The accepted answer uses the `preview` package, which is not what you want - see the [answer using TikZ's `external` library](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23563/fitting-page-size-to-a-tikz-figure/23565#23565) instead.)

Comment: I have an idea for an `standalone` class option which crops a `tikzpicture` or similar but doesn't use `preview`. This should also avoid issues like this.

Comment: See my recent answer to [Transparency in tikz, preview package and xelatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21011/transparency-in-tikz-preview-package-and-xelatex/32279#32279) which be a poosibility for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up using the `external library`, as diabonas suggested.

Here's an example with XeTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \definecolor{blue}{cmyk}{1,1,0,0.07}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzset{external/system call={xelatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
\tikzset{external/force remake=true} 

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{place}=[circle,draw=blue,fill=blue!20,line width=2pt]

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) [place] {Ti\textit{k}Z};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

One has to compile using `-shellescape`.

A minor inconvenience is, that the appropriately cropped file is named `<filename>-figure0`.

Comment: You can change the filenames, it's described in the manual how. Edit: Add `\tikzsetnextfilename{file name}` before a `tikzpicture`. The name will only apply to the next `tikzpicture` or `\tikz` command.

Comment: @Torbjorn: Thanks, that's useful. Unfortunately, one still ends up with two output files.

Comment: I usually get headache when using `external` library due to a) pdflatex runs out of memory very soon; and 2) When using `lualatex`, it stops working : which can be resolved by putting `\RequirePackage{luatex85,shellescp}` at the top of  your documents (at least with `texlive-2016` on `openSUSE-42.2`.

Answer (score 78):

You can use the [`standalone`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) class for this. In v0.x it used `preview` internally, but for v1.x it also has an alternative `crop` option, which works similar to the `preview` option/package, but avoids its issues with XeTeX.

There is now (v1.0) also a `tikz` class option which turns any (outer) `tikzpicture` into a single tight page. This avoids issues with trailing implicit paragraphs. In addition it automatically loads the `tikz` package.

```
% tikzpic.tex
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}% 'crop' is the default for v1.0, before it was 'preview'
%\usetikzlibrary{...}% tikz package already loaded by 'tikz' option
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (10,10); % ...
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Then compile it as usual with `pdflatex` or `xelatex` etc.

To include this `tikzpicture` into a main document load the `standalone` *package* there with the option `mode=buildnew`. Then use `\includestandalone[<options>]{<filename>}` instead of `\includegraphics`. This will compile all includes standalone files automatically as graphics and build these graphics if the source file is newer than the existing graphics file. This needs `-shell-escape` to be enabled to allow the main LaTeX run to call further LaTeX compilers.
See the `standalone` manual for more details.

```
% main.tex
% compile with `pdflatex -shell-escape main` or `xelatex  -shell-escape main`
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mode=buildnew]{standalone}% requires -shell-escape
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{...}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum ...

\includestandalone[width=.8\textwidth]{tikzpic}

Lorem ipsum ...
\end{document}
```

Comment: `mv standalone.cls swiss-army-knife.cls`.  Is there *anything* the standalone class can't do?

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Yes, it doesn't include much support for math yet, especially displaymath.

Comment: Unless I have something mis-configured (or my XeTeX is too old), `mode=buildnew` does not work with XeTeX.

Comment: @Blair: `buildnew` requires some pdfTeX primitive to read the file date which isn't available in XeTeX. I think I need to update the manual accordantly.

Comment: @MartinScharrer OK, thanks for clarifying that. You might want to edit your final example here too :). Thanks for all the useful packages you have written also.

Comment: I tried to add this animation: http://www.texample.net/media/tikz/examples/TEX/animated-definite-integral.tex with this method to another document; but I was not successful. The resulting pdf was empty! Is there any idea?

Comment: The top code does not run in LuaLatex either. (I was unfortunately forced to switch to LuaLatex because it is required to use the tikz-feynman package.) 

I see in the comments above that a similar statement was made about XeTeX. But that was years ago, why does the answer still state quite optimistically: " Then compile it as usual with pdflatex or xelatex etc." when only pdflatex can be used.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Does this way of building a tikz file only if source file is newer work also if the tikz file is including data from another data file?

Comment: @Abhinav: No, it only checks the .tex and the .PDF file modification dates.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a combination of standard article class and `pdfcrop` or the cropping facilities of `adjustbox` would be a work around.

So, you make the picture in a separate file with `article` class, for instance. Then you use `clipbox` from the `adjustbox` package to clip the image included via `\includegraphics` to the part you actually want...

Comment: But the standalone package uses preview internally so is subject to the same problems as preview with xelatex (see link in the question).

Comment: @AndrewStacey Yes I'd misread the question. Fixed now.

Comment: Before using `pdfcrop`, don't forget to include `\thispagestyle{empty}` in your source otherways you will get the page number which will be include into cropped result.