# disabling page number from tikz-uml diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, page-numbering, tikz-uml

I'm trying to use the tikz-uml package for generating uml diagrams. As I was trying, I found that for some reason page number appears at the bottom of the page. I tried to disable it by using `\pagestyle{empty}`. With this the page number disappears from the page. But when I include the picture in the latex document, the figure caption comes at the bottom of the page, meaning, the diagram occupies the full page.

I have used here an example from tikz-uml package, which generates the page number. Note you need to download the tikz-uml package from 
http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php?lang=en

Can any one help me with this issue?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, svgnames]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\textwidth 18.5cm
\textheight 25.5cm
\hoffset=-2.9cm
\voffset=-2.9cm

\sloppy
\hyphenpenalty 10000000

\date{}
\title{}
\author{}

\lstdefinelanguage{tikzuml}{language=[LaTeX]TeX, classoffset=0, morekeywords={umlbasiccomponent, umlprovidedinterface, umlrequiredinterface, umldelegateconnector, umlassemblyconnector, umlVHVassemblyconnector, umlHVHassemblyconnector, umlnote, umlusecase, umlactor, umlinherit, umlassoc, umlVHextend, umlinclude, umlstateinitial, umlbasicstate, umltrans, umlstatefinal, umlVHtrans, umlHVtrans, umldatabase, umlmulti, umlobject, umlfpart, umlcreatecall, umlclass, umlvirt, umlunicompo, umlimport, umlaggreg}, keywordstyle=\color{DarkBlue}, classoffset=1, morekeywords={umlcomponent, umlsystem, umlstate, umlseqdiag, umlcall, umlcallself, umlfragment, umlpackage}, keywordstyle=\color{DarkRed}, classoffset=0,  sensitive=true, morecomment=[l]{\%}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlcomponent}{A}
\umlbasiccomponent{B}
\umlbasiccomponent[y=-2]{C}

\umlrequiredinterface[interface=C-interface]{C}
\umlprovidedinterface[interface=B-interface, with port, distance=3cm, padding=2.5cm]{B}
\end{umlcomponent}
\umlbasiccomponent[x=-10,y=1]{D}
\umlbasiccomponent[x=3,y=-7.5]{E}
\umlbasiccomponent[x=-2, y=-9]{F}
\umlbasiccomponent[x=-7,y=-8]{G}
\umlbasiccomponent[x=-7,y=-11]{H}

\umlassemblyconnector[interface=DA, with port, name=toto]{D}{A}
\umldelegateconnector{A-west-port}{B-west-interface}
\umlVHVassemblyconnector[interface=AE, with port]{A}{E}
\umlHVHassemblyconnector[interface=EF, with port, first arm]{E}{F}
\umlHVHassemblyconnector[interface=GHF, with port, arm2=-2cm, last arm]{G}{F}
\umlHVHassemblyconnector[with port, arm2=-2cm, last arm]{H}{F}

\umlnote[x=-4, y=4, width=3.4cm]{B-west-interface}{I am the node named B-west-interface}
\umlnote[x=2, y=4, width=3.4cm]{C-east-interface}{I am the node named C-east-interface}
\umlnote[x=-8.5, y=-2, width=3.4cm]{toto-interface}{I am the node named toto-interface}
\umlnote[x=-5.5, y=-4.5, width=3.4cm]{A-south-port}{I am the node named A-south-port}
\umlnote[x=-1, y=-6, width=3.4cm]{AE-interface}{I am the node named AE-interface}
\umlnote[x=2, y=-11, width=3.4cm]{F-east-port}{I am the node named F-east-port}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: If you just want to produce your TiKZ scheme as an independent figure with anything else around, I'd suggest using [`standalone`](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone/) class, presented in ['Standalone' TikZ pictures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51761/1952). It will produce a cropped pdf file. You won't have to define, margins, pagestyles, ...

Answer (score 1):

It works:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, svgnames]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\textwidth 18.5cm
\textheight 25.5cm
\hoffset=-2.9cm
\voffset=-2.9cm

\sloppy
\hyphenpenalty 10000000

\date{}
\title{}
\author{}

\lstdefinelanguage{tikzuml}{language=[LaTeX]TeX, classoffset=0, morekeywords={umlbasiccomponent, umlprovidedinterface, umlrequiredinterface, umldelegateconnector, umlassemblyconnector, umlVHVassemblyconnector, umlHVHassemblyconnector, umlnote, umlusecase, umlactor, umlinherit, umlassoc, umlVHextend, umlinclude, umlstateinitial, umlbasicstate, umltrans, umlstatefinal, umlVHtrans, umlHVtrans, umldatabase, umlmulti, umlobject, umlfpart, umlcreatecall, umlclass, umlvirt, umlunicompo, umlimport, umlaggreg}, keywordstyle=\color{DarkBlue}, classoffset=1, morekeywords={umlcomponent, umlsystem, umlstate, umlseqdiag, umlcall, umlcallself, umlfragment, umlpackage}, keywordstyle=\color{DarkRed}, classoffset=0,  sensitive=true, morecomment=[l]{\%}}


\pagestyle{empty} %the only change
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlcomponent}{A}
\umlbasiccomponent{B}
\umlbasiccomponent[y=-2]{C}

\umlrequiredinterface[interface=C-interface]{C}
\umlprovidedinterface[interface=B-interface, with port, distance=3cm, padding=2.5cm]{B}
\end{umlcomponent}
\umlbasiccomponent[x=-10,y=1]{D}
\umlbasiccomponent[x=3,y=-7.5]{E}
\umlbasiccomponent[x=-2, y=-9]{F}
\umlbasiccomponent[x=-7,y=-8]{G}
\umlbasiccomponent[x=-7,y=-11]{H}

\umlassemblyconnector[interface=DA, with port, name=toto]{D}{A}
\umldelegateconnector{A-west-port}{B-west-interface}
\umlVHVassemblyconnector[interface=AE, with port]{A}{E}
\umlHVHassemblyconnector[interface=EF, with port, first arm]{E}{F}
\umlHVHassemblyconnector[interface=GHF, with port, arm2=-2cm, last arm]{G}{F}
\umlHVHassemblyconnector[with port, arm2=-2cm, last arm]{H}{F}

\umlnote[x=-4, y=4, width=3.4cm]{B-west-interface}{I am the node named B-west-interface}
\umlnote[x=2, y=4, width=3.4cm]{C-east-interface}{I am the node named C-east-interface}
\umlnote[x=-8.5, y=-2, width=3.4cm]{toto-interface}{I am the node named toto-interface}
\umlnote[x=-5.5, y=-4.5, width=3.4cm]{A-south-port}{I am the node named A-south-port}
\umlnote[x=-1, y=-6, width=3.4cm]{AE-interface}{I am the node named AE-interface}
\umlnote[x=2, y=-11, width=3.4cm]{F-east-port}{I am the node named F-east-port}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I went for \usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%

Comment: The `\pagestyle{empty}` does not solve the issue of generating pdf of right size. But, it does remove the page number from the bottom of the page. I tried, solution provided by Ignasi. By using `\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}`, I was able to generate the picture of desired size. @Ignasi