# Import tex graphics to my main tex document

Tags: pgfplots, graphics, import

I want to create various plots with tikz package. I don't want to have the code for the plots in my main tex document because it's pretty messy. Is there a way to keep the tex code to different documents and just import the generated plots?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In addition to the `\input` suggestion below, the `standalone` package/class may be of interest, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51761/586

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `include` and `input` commands in order to use code from another .tex file in your main document. [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include) is useful for choosing which one is best suited for your task.

Comment: For `tikzpicture`s you want to use`\input`.