# Meaning of "Diagrams should be prepared in .ps (postscript) or .eps format"

Tags: diagrams

The homepage of the [Journal of Integer Sequences](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/) says:

> If there are accompanying style files or diagrams, please be sure to include them. Diagrams should be prepared in .ps (postscript) or .eps format, not pdf or other formats. If there are multiple files, please consider sending them as a Unix tar or zip file.

Does this mean that preparing diagrams using TikZ is allowed or not?

What about preparing them as an image (say, .jpg or .gif) and including them?

Comment: `.jpg` and `.gif` are bitmap formats. This is not a good way to store diagrams.

Comment: We can answer the technical part (_e.g._ 'How do I make EPS/PDF files for individual TikZ graphics?"), but the 'policy' part is up to the journal in question.

Comment: Might be an idea to simply ask the journal. A lot of journals have not updated their recommendations for years. Many of the do not realise that most people do not use or does not even know that Postscript or EPS is anymore.

Comment: It means that they are several years behind technology-wise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can prepare your diagrams using TikZ, but you ought to convert them to EPS afterwards. It's best to have them as seperate `standalone` files.

For more information, see:

- [Export eps figures from TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8641/export-eps-figures-from-tikz)
- ['Standalone' TikZ pictures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32127/standalone-tikz-pictures)

But the basic idea is the following:

1. Prepare your figures using the `standalone` class, for example:

   ```
   \documentclass[crop,tikz,margin=2pt]{standalone}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw{<->} (0,0) -- (1,2);
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
   ```
2. Convert this separate small PDF file to EPS by `pdf2ps file.pdf file.eps`.
3. Use `latex document.tex && dvips document.dvi` for compiling your paper.
4. Verify that the figures are fine. Minor problems with cropping can appear with this approach.

Comment: I'd first try TikZ code inlined in the LaTeX source of the article and see whether it passes the editorial system and whether the proof looks ok.

Comment: @AlexG After seeing how the typesetting process in the journals work, I make the small extra effort and externalize all my figures. It doesn't hurt and it prevents bad things happening :)