# tex input or include another tex file

Tags: tex-core

In a tex file, I need to draw a system diagram, so I put it in a separate tex like diagram.tex:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and then in main.tex:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\begin{document}
\section{sectionA}
\include{diagram} % I also tried input the same error. I wish diagram.tex figure could be inserted at this place.
\subsection{subsectionA}
\section{sectionB}
\end{document}
```

besides:
running diagram.tex alone in latex gives:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `standalone.cls' not found.Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)Enter file name:! Emergency stop.<read > \usepackage
```

So the question would be how to insert a standalone tex file? And is it possible to run a standalone tex alone? I am also studying `tikz`, while demos I found are mostly using `standalone`.

Comment: I think the answer is in post : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32127/standalone-tikz-pictures

Comment: it is possible (but unnecessarily complicated) to make that work but it is much simpler to just have the `tikzpicture` in a separate file (no `\documentclass` etc) then you can simply `\input` it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle make what work but complicated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}` load `tikz`, so it is not need to load it again with `\usepackage{tikz}`.
- in main document you need to load

  - `standalone` for stripping out preamble in your `diagra` file
  - `tikz` with necessary `tikz` libraries

i.e. all packages used in included document.

so, your codes should be

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage{standalone} % <--- added
\usepackage{tikz}       % <--- added

\begin{document}
\section{sectionA}
    \input{diagram}     % <--- changed
\end{document}
```

Comment: are  you suggesting using `input` instead of `include`

Comment: @Tiina, yes. i assume, that included file should not start on new page (this happens with `\include`).