# Using standalone package to reduce tikz compile time

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, standalone, shell-escape

I am using `standalone` package by Martin Scharrer in a report. I read in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51761/9279) answer by Martin that if the document loads with a `[mode=buildnew]{standalone}` package, then for each picture that is included using `\includestandalone[<options>]{<filename>}`, a compilation using the `pdflatex -shell-escape main`  will compile all `\includesstandalone`'ed files automatically as graphics and build these graphics **if the source file is newer** than the existing graphics file.

My question is, is this valid also if the `tikzpic.tex` file includes plot data from another data file ? Because if the changes are made in the data file, then would the `standalone` package will still be including the pdf of plot of old data?

Comment: No, it isn‘t. There is not a make-like transitive dependency tracking, but basically a simple comparison of the file dates.

Comment: @Daniel ok, then should I close this question? Or can you put your reply in an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: If you use the `external` library, you can declare a dependency for a picture on another file, I think. However, I don't think the `standalone` strategy can do this. (I'm not sure as I always externalise rather than using this functionality from `standalone` and just use `standalone` for its inputting features.)

Comment: @cfr Can you add a MWE to Daniel's answer using 'external' library?

Comment: Daniel's answer is completely different and has nothing to do with the `external` library. You are less likely to get answers with MWEs when you don't bother to provide an MWE yourself. Anyway, my comment doesn't answer the question because it by-passes `standalone`'s support for including compiled pictures altogether: if you externalise, the standalone file is just input and Ti*k*Z figures out whether to compile each `tikzpicture` in the document (whether in another file or not).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the `[mode=buildnew`] option of `standalone` is pretty nifty, it does not work transitively. That is, it invokes the recompilation **only if the source file itself is newer than the PDF**, but does not extend this test recursively to further dependencies of the source file.

A possible, but untested, workaround might be to use `[mode=build]`, that is, always invoke the compiler, but use either `make` (with an appropriate `Makefile`) or `latexmk` as the compiler executable for standalone. (Look for `latex` + `latexoptions` or `command` in the `standalone` documentation).

Thereby, the dependency handling would be delegated to `make` or `latexmk`, which consider recursive dependecies. However, the price would be slightly higher compilation times, as the external compiler is aways invoked – even if it does not need to do any work.